# Using Mongodb: TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Ran in to this problem while doing https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/store-data-in-mongodb

error message was

```
swyx:~/workspace $ learnyoumongo run find.js
/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.1/lib/node_modules/learnyoumongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:231
        process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                      ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined
    at Exercise.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.1/lib/node_modules/learnyoumongo/exercises/find/exercise.js:37:5)
    at next (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.1/lib/node_modules/learnyoumongo/node_modules/workshopper-exercise/exercise.js:271:17)
    at Exercise.end (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.1/lib/node_modules/learnyoumongo/node_modules/workshopper-exercise/exercise.js:277:5)
    at Workshopper.end (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.1/lib/node_modules/learnyoumongo/node_modules/workshopper/workshopper.js:191:12)
    at Workshopper.done (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.1/lib/node_modules/learnyoumongo/node_modules/workshopper/workshopper.js:323:19)
    at Exercise.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.1/lib/node_modules/learnyoumongo/node_modules/workshopper-exercise/exercise.js:160:14)
    at /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.1/lib/node_modules/learnyoumongo/node_modules/workshopper-exercise/exercise.js:147:16
    at /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.1/lib/node_modules/learnyoumongo/exercises/find/exercise.js:20:21
    at /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.1/lib/node_modules/learnyoumongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongo_client.js:238:20
    at /home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.1/lib/node_modules/learnyoumongo/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:242:14
```

there are other similar question on here but none of them were describing this exact problem

for reference this was the (valid) code i was running it on

```
var mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient
var age = process.argv[2]

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/learnyoumongo'

mongo.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err
  var parrots = db.collection('parrots')
  parrots.find({
    age: {
      $gt: +age
    }
  }).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(docs)
    db.close()
  })
})
```

Comment: i have found my own solution and posted below to help people in future

Answer (score 1):

solution was my mongodb server experienced an unexpected shutdown overnight and wasn't even running. to start it back up again you have to recover (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/recover-data-following-unexpected-shutdown/) and then restart.

Comment: You should add a pm2 service that will keep awake your server

Comment: ok. i dont know what pm2 is but i'll look it up when i have need for it

Answer (score 0):

In version 2.x of the MongoDB native NodeJS driver you would get the database object as an argument to the connect callback:

```
mongo.connect(url, (err, db) => {
  // Database returned
});
```

But According to the changelog for 3.0 you now get a client object containing the database object instead:

```
mongo.connect(url, (err, client) => {
  // Client returned
  var db = client.db('mytestingdb');
});
```

The close() method has also been moved to the client so that you have to write `client.close();` instead of `db.close()`